# Selenium for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am relatively new to Selenium.
Currently in my company we use Eclipse to create and run our testing automation (Maven/Cucumber/Selenium).
We also use IntelliJ IDEA for Java development.
My question would be if it is possible to use IntelliJ IDEA for testing automation similarly like we use Eclipse (Maven/Cucumber/Selenium)?  I mean to build test automation scripts.
If yes, so you could you kindly recommend any tutorial where it is explained how build those projects for IntelliJ IDEA.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Best way to learn Selenium is YouTube. You can also try Udemy, SkillShare and other online courses.

Comment: To get started with Selenium in IntelliJ I'd recommend you check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selenium.html .

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will consider your advices, Team. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this question has a simple answer. Whatever your company does in Eclipse, you can do in InteliJ.

BOTH Eclipse and InteliJ are IDE's (An integrated development environment for building applications that combines common developer tools into a single graphical user interface). So basically, consider them both like "code editors". There is really no difference in using Eclipse or InteliJ (maybe some UI differences).

Personally, I prefer InteliJ based on cleaner UI. You pick yours.

Here is one useful tutorial. Good luck :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPLk4Z0U0yQ

Comment: Thank you, Josip.  This video is really helpful.  If by any chance you will remember some more courses on LinkedIn, Udemy, YouTube etc., so, please let me know. I am really interested in this topic since it starts to be important for my job. Again, thank you for your time and effort.